# How do I read values (PHP defined constants) from wp-config.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, constants, config

I need to get username, password etc from the `wp-config` file to connect to a custom PDO database.

Currently I have another file where I have this info, but I would like to only use the `wp-config`.

So how can I read the different properties of `wp-config`?

Answer (score 27):

I have even defined my own constants in in wp-config.php and managed to retrieve them in theme without any includes.

*wp-config.php*

```
define('DEFAULT_ACCESS', 'employee');
```

*functions.php*

```
echo "DEFAULT_ACCESS :".DEFAULT_ACCESS;
```

outputs *DEFAULT_ACCESS :employee*

Answer (score 13):

I would just include the file then I would have access to the variable in it varibales.

```
<?php
  require_once 'wp-config.php';
  echo DB_NAME;
?>
```

This is assuming you're on the same server and you can access wp-config.php through the file system.

If you're doing this for a plugin, these values are already available. You won't need to include the file again.

Answer (score 8):

You can get all the global constants from wp-config.php simply echo the const like that:

```
<?php
  echo DB_HOST;
  echo DB_NAME;
  echo DB_USER;
  echo DB_PASSWORD;
```

Answer (score 6):

[Here](https://rokaweb.ir/read-wpconfig-php/) is a function to read all WP DB defines:

```
function get_wordpress_data() {
    $content = @file_get_contents( '../wp-config.php' );

    if( ! $content ) {
        return false;
    }

    $params = [
        'db_name' => "/define.+?'DB_NAME'.+?'(.*?)'.+/",
        'db_user' => "/define.+?'DB_USER'.+?'(.*?)'.+/",
        'db_password' => "/define.+?'DB_PASSWORD'.+?'(.*?)'.+/",
        'db_host' => "/define.+?'DB_HOST'.+?'(.*?)'.+/",
        'table_prefix' => "/\\\$table_prefix.+?'(.+?)'.+/",
    ];

    $return = [];

    foreach( $params as $key => $value ) {

        $found = preg_match_all( $value, $content, $result );

        if( $found ) {
            $return[ $key ] = $result[ 1 ][ 0 ];
        } else {
            $return[ $key ] = false;
        }

    }

    return $return;
}
```

this returns an array like this:

```
array (size=5)
  'db_name' => string '.........'
  'db_user' => string '.........'
  'db_password' => string '.........'
  'db_host' => string 'localhost'
  'table_prefix' => string 'wp_'
```

Comment: Very useful snippet, however much of that code is irrelevant here.

Comment: Would be even better if the script could skip commented lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to DB, for current versions of PHP, using **mysqli** extention is recommended (mysql extention is going to deprecate):

```
require_once "../wp-config.php"; // path to wp-config depends on your file locatoin
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add required wp-load.php file.
you can use all wordpress functionality like
get_recent_posts() and many more...