# Wordpress: Is it possible to access wp_config.php file directly?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am admin user of a Wordpress application. I don't have access the database configuration variables -  username, password. I know only hostname value. So, to get the values of these variables, access to wp_config.php file is required. From admin section, I am unable to find these configuration values.

`So, is there any way to directly access wp_config.php file?`

Comment: Short answer is `No` you can't.

Answer (score 0):

This will help.... You can get some of the details in the connection string... By running queries from one of the php files in your theme.

[How do I read values from wp-config.php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921229/how-do-i-read-values-from-wp-config-php)

Answer (score 0):

help you this link to config file:

[wp-config.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)

---

One of the most important files in your WordPress installation is the wp-config.php file. This file is located in the root of your WordPress file directory and contains your website's base configuration details, such as database connection information.

When you first download WordPress, the wp-config.php file isn’t included. The WordPress setup process will create a wp-config.php file for you based on the information you provide.

Advanced users can manually create a wp-config.php file by locating the sample file named "wp-config-sample.php" (located in the root install-directory), editing it as required, and then saving it as wp-config.php.

> NOTE: The contents of the wp-config-sample.php file are in a very
>   specific order. The order matters. If you already have a wp-config.php
>   file, rearranging the contents of the file may create errors on your
>   blog.

To change the wp-config.php file for your installation, you will need this information:

- Database Name 
     Database Name used by WordPress
- Database Username 
     Username used to access Database
- Database Password 
     Password used by Username to access Database
- Database Host 
     The hostname of your Database Server. A port number, Unix socket file path or pipe may be needed as well.

If your hosting provider installed WordPress for you, get the information from them. If you manage your own web server or hosting account, you will have this information as a result of creating the database and user.
Configure Database Settings

> Important: never use a word processor like Microsoft Word for editing
>   WordPress files!

Locate the file wp-config-sample.php in the base directory of your WordPress directory and open in a text editor.

> NOTE: Since Version 2.6, wp-config.php can be moved to the directory
>   directly above the WordPress application directory.

Default wp-config-sample.php

> NOTE: This is an example of a default wp-config-sample.php. The values
>   here are examples to show you what to do. Do not change these details
>   here by editing this page, change them on your web server. If you make
>   changes here by using the edit button, they will not work and you will
>   be showing your password details to the world.

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'username_here' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
```

> NOTE: Text inside /* */ are comments, for information purposes only.
>   Set Database Name

Replace 'database_name_here', with the name of your database, e.g. MyDatabaseName.

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'MyDatabaseName' ); // Example MySQL database name
```

Set Database User

Replace 'username_here', with the name of your username e.g. MyUserName.

```
define( 'DB_USER', 'MyUserName' ); // Example MySQL username
```

Set Database Password

Replace 'password_here', with the your password, e.g. MyPassWord.

```
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'MyPassWord' ); // Example MySQL password
```

Set Database Host

Replace 'localhost', with the name of your database host, e.g. MyDatabaseHost. A port number or Unix socket file path may be needed as well.

```
define( 'DB_HOST', 'MyDatabaseHost' ); // Example MySQL Database host
```

> NOTE: There is a good chance you will NOT have to change it. If you
>   are unsure, try installing with the default value of 'localhost' and
>   see if it works. If the install fails, contact your web hosting
>   provider. Possible DB_HOST values

Different hosting companies use different network settings for their mysql databases. If your hosting company is listed below in the left column, the value on the right is similar to the correct value for DB_HOST. Contact your tech support and/or search your hosting companies online Documentation to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't access wp-config.php file directly. Try to get the details by downloading the wp-config file from server using FTP credentials.

**OR**

Include the file name & echo the wanted info from wp-config file.

```
<?php include "wp-config.php";?>
Database Name: <?php echo DB_NAME; ?>
Database User:  <?php echo DB_USER; ?>
Database password:  <?php echo DB_PASSWORD; ?>
Database Host:  <?php echo DB_HOST; ?>
```

Note: Assuming you are working in same server. If you are working with theme/plugins means don't need to include wp-config.php file, its already available.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the file directly,But you can get these DB details using the following code in any template file or header.php :

```
global $wpdb;
echo "dbuser            : ".$wpdb->dbuser;
echo "<br/>dbpassword   : ".$wpdb->dbpassword;
echo "<br/>dbname       : ".$wpdb->dbname;
echo "<br/>dbhost       : ".$wpdb->dbhost;
```