# How can I access database of Worldpress website in Django Application?

Tags: django, database, wordpress

I have multiple blogging websites which are made in WordPress and hosted on hostinger. I want to access my WordPress database so that I can keep a record of when I have added articles on which website. How can I do that?

Comment: wordpress system should have some datatabase configuration information.  You need connect to the target database based on that information and do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really wan't to get databas information, the only way is to read and parse the wp-config.php file.

Here you find [regex to read all constants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54440300/18353089)